# Power BI enlarges visuals based on screen size in Power BI service

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am having an issue that my Power BI report is resizing visuals based on the screen size in the Power BI service. Which is causing issues on bigger screens.

The first image shows the issue I am having when viewing my report in the Power BI service on a external larger monitor.

The second image shows how the report looks in my Power BI Desktop dev file. And when viewed on my laptop screen in the Power BI service.

[image]

[image]

The image shows a matrix table that has been enlarged with a scroll bar. This is being viewed on an external monitor. However in my Power BI desktop dev file this aligns the way you would imagine. Also if viewed on a laptop it aligns correctly.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Ahh yes, this is quite an annoying issue. Maybe this link will help -> [Change the display of a report page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-report-view) Quote: If you don't want any scroll bars, but want to make the best use of your screen size, select Fit to Page.